# ¿Existe algún sustantivo específico para las "catas olfativas"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Anoche a nuestro hijo mayor le dio por interesarse por las especias, así que saqué unos cuantos botes de especias y se los di a oler para ver si los olores le gustaban o no. Bromeando dije que habíamos hecho una "cata olfativa", y ya me surgió la duda.

La palabra *[cata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7srabDf)* se refiere a la "acción y efecto de catar":

> **[catar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7ujKcvv)**
>
> Del lat. *captāre* 'coger', 'buscar'.
>
> 1. tr. Probar, gustar algo para examinar su sabor o sazón.

Es decir, una cata implica examinar un [sabor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WtqKHWN) (sensación producida en el órgano del gusto), pero no un olor. Así que pregunto, ¿existe algún término usado para una "cata olfativa" en la que lo que se examine sean olores?

Comment: Investigando un poco veo artículos en el que encuadran la _fase olfativa_ dentro del conjunto de la cata (de vinos), dando a entender que consideran la _cata_ como algo que contiene el sabor pero también los otros sentidos.

Comment: Nótese que podemos establecer la siguiente relación navegando por el DRAE: catar => gustar => experimentar => Probar y examinar las propiedades de algo. Entiendo que el olor es una propiedad. Esta secuencia deja libre con qué sentido se realiza la prueba.

Comment: Existen catas de perfumes y parece que las llaman así: *catas*. Obviamente no los prueban, solo los huelen.

Comment: @blonfu es cierto, y de hecho yo pensaba que el término "cata olfativa" me lo había inventado pero también arroja algunos resultados en Google. Puedes ponerlo como respuesta aportando algunos ejemplos.

Comment: @blonfu trabajé en una empresa de cosméticos y periodicamente hacían catas de perfumes entre los empleados.

Comment: La palabra que me viene en mente es **Aromachología**.

Comment: También se usa el término "cata" en geología, cuando se perfora y se saca un testigo para ver la composición del terreno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La página de Wikipedia sobre [cata de **vinos**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cata_de_vinos) define la cata como un proceso que consta de tres fases: visual, olfativa y gustativa (por ese orden).
El temario de las asignaturas de "[Análisis sensorial](https://aps.unirioja.es/GuiasDocentes/servlet/agetguiahtml?2018-19,703G,544)" y "[Ampliación de Análisis sensorial](https://aps.unirioja.es/GuiasDocentes/servlet/agetguiahtml?2018-19,703G,547)" del Grado de Enología de la Universidad de La Rioja incluyen la vista y el olfato como partes integrales del proceso de cata.
El temario de "[Análisis sensorial](http://asignaturas.uca.es/asig/40212021/?titul=40212&asign=40212021)" para el Grado en Química y Enología de la Universidad de Cádiz prefiere usar el término "análisis sensorial", pero también incluye la fase olfativa dentro del proceso. Ídem para los Grados en Enología de la [Universidad de Tarragona](https://moodle.urv.cat/docnet/guia_docent/index.php?centre=19&ensenyament=1922&assignatura=19224107&fitxa_apartat=57&any_academic=2018_19&any_academic=2018_19), de la [Universidad de Palencia / Valladolid [PDF]](https://alojamientos.uva.es/guia_docente/uploads/2018/444/42042/1/Documento.pdf)...

Son [varias](https://www.catadelvino.com/blog-cata-vino/la-cata-de-vino-cual-es-su-definicion) [las](http://www.aromasenmicopa.com/2012/09/definicion-y-tipos-de-cata/) [páginas](http://www.eventosalicante.org/2014/11/26/uso-y-ciencia-de-la-cata/) que tachan la definición de 'cata' hallada en el DLE como demasiado restrictiva, y prefieren usar la de la [Asociación Francesa de Normalización](https://www.afnor.org/):

> Operación que consiste en analizar y apreciar los caracteres organolépticos, y más concretamente, las características olfativas y gustativas de un producto.

Esta definición, que además está recogida en la [norma ISO 5492:2010](https://www.aenor.com/normas-y-libros/buscador-de-normas/une/?c=N0045382), incluye igualmente la prueba olfativa como parte del proceso de cata.
Lo mismo sucede si abrimos el abanico y consultamos la [formación](http://icaformacion.com/genera_pdf.php?idc=18674) [relacionada](https://web.escueladecata.com/escueladecata/Cursos/Cursos%20presenciales/CursosNewsModule/displayNews/3f00190e6e9199bf6663479ca5e15887/96ca62a499ce6d1b6acd62da09e3c224) con la cata de **otros alimentos** como el chocolate o el queso.

Si nos salimos del ámbito de lo alimentario y nos vamos a algo puramente olfativo como son los **perfumes**, vemos que incluso aquí se usa en ocasiones el término 'cata' en [noticias](https://www.clarin.com/ciudades/Lecciones-olfato-cata-perfumes_0_HJgTpv-C.html), [eventos](http://www.telva.com/2016/08/29/belleza/1472456031.html) y [cursos](http://www.lesecretdumarais.com/blog/catas-de-perfumes-cursos-y-talleres-olfativos-en-le-secret-du-marais/), aun siendo un análisis que necesariamente excluye el sentido del gusto y se centra en el del olfato.
Revisando la oferta formativa y contenidos del *[Institut supérieur international du parfum, de la cosmétique et de l'aromatique alimentaire](https://www.isipca.fr/formations-scientifiques-techniques/european-fragrance-and-cosmetics-master-university-degree)*, de la *[Université Européenne Des Saveurs & des Senteurs](https://www.uess.fr/formations)* y de la *[British Society of Perfumes](http://www.bsp.org.uk)*, no he identificado ningún término específico para referirse a estas catas olfativas.

Mi conclusión es que los términos usados hoy en día son: "cata" y "análisis sensorial". El primero es más popular y puede referirse a catas completas (vista, gusto, olfato e incluso tacto) o parciales; el segundo parece restringido a ámbitos técnicos o académicos.

Cabe resaltar que las especias son un producto alimentario que puede ser olido, pero también tocado y probado; una cata de especias puede incluir las tres fases. Si la limitamos a solo una de las fases, sigue siendo una cata, pero limitada.

Por tanto, en mi opinión "cata olfativa" es el término mejor y más adecuado en este caso, e hiciste bien en emplearlo.

Answer (score 3):

Me temo que no hay una palabra, en español, para referirse a lo que preguntas.

Lo interesante en la pregunta que planteas, creo yo, es que la palabra que da origen a tu duda —`catar`— es única al idioma español y, además,<sup>1</sup> se ha usado históricamente para referirse a la **acción de probar un alimento o una bebida** para gustar de su sazón.<sup>2</sup> De allí, que en ciertos contextos, resulte extraño, con toda razón, hablar de una "cata olfativa".

Ahora bien, dado lo que mencionan en los comentarios de tu pregunta (que hay quien habla de catas de perfumes, o, como tal, la cata olfativa de alguna bebida, como el vino), podemos estar ante un **neologismo semántico**, en donde el significado de la palabra `catar` se modifica para ser más amplio: no sólo se trata de degustar alimentos, pero, en general, examinar y experimentar las cualidades de algo (como un perfume, una especia, una bebida, etc.) Y como ocurre en la mayoría de los neologismos semánticos, esto muy probablemente se debe al uso particular de la palabra en algún área técnica o artística.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Su raíz etimológica (*captāre*) no derivó en palabras semánticamente equivalentes en otros idiomas.

<sup>2</sup> Una búsqueda en el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.0.0.0.0.) señala que las entradas más antiguas de la palabra `catar` la definen como sinónimo de `mirar` o como la acción de `probar o gustar un alimento` (siglo XVII). Esta definición se mantuvo constante a lo largo del tiempo (salvo, claro está, por la parte de `catar` como sinónimo de `mirar`). Lo mismo ocurre al hacer una búsqueda en el [Córpus Histórico del Español de México](http://www.corpus.unam.mx:8080/unificado/index.jsp?c=chem#) —como punto de referencia no Ibérico—. Esto sugiere que el significado de la palabra (entendida como la acción de probar alimentos o bebdias) se ha mantenido "constante" a lo largo del tiempo y el espacio.

<sup>3</sup> Los neologismos semánticos son un fenómeno de la lengua que ya ha sido previamente estudiado. Es el mismo proceso que nos dio expresiones adverbiales como "`matar el rato`" o palabras con nuevos significados, como `azafata` (en el sentido de `aeromoza`).